# Unexpected Indent on Python Error

Tags: python, indentation

Can someone tell me what is causing the unexpected indent / expecting an indent error in this code? I don't quite understand it so some help would be nice

```
print """77
"""
print '1. Go out through the door'
print '2. Stay in the room and find more clues'
option = raw_input('Which Option? ')
break
if option == "1":
    print """You attempt to open the door, but it is locked. After a few minutes of hopeless knob-turning, you finally give up. What do you do?
    """
    print '1. Stay in the room and find more clues'
    print '2. Attempt to use force to break the door'
    cluedoor = raw_input('Which Option? ')
    break
if option == "2":
    print """test123
    """
    print '1. Inspect the Rusted Cabinet'
    print '2. Go out in to the hallway'
    labhall = raw_input('Which Option? ')
    if labhall == "1": 
        print '222'
    if labhall == "2": 
        print '2'
    if cluedoor == "1":
    break
    test = raw_input("test")
```

Comment: Why do you have so many triple-quoted strings? If you just want to print an additional blank line, that can be done with a bare `print`. For example, `print 'blah blah'; print` would print `blah blah` followed by an empty line.

Comment: The `break` statement is not going to be allowed in the `if` block in any case. Even if you indent the `break` statement, you will get a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: When the interpreter throws an error it will give you the exact line number of the Indentation error. **Did you try looking there?**

Answer (score 1):

An "IndentationError" means the interpreter didn't find an indentation when expected (for example, after a `for` or `if`) or found an indentation when not expected.

To fix your problem, replace:

```
if cluedoor == "1":
break
```

with:

```
if cluedoor == "1":
    break
```

Note, however, that `cluedoor` is not defined in the section where this `if` statement is executed.  With some rearrangement, the code can be executed:

```
print '1. Go out through the door'
print '2. Stay in the room and find more clues'
option = raw_input('Which Option? ')
if option == "1":
    print """You attempt to open the door, but it is locked. After a few minutes of hopeless knob-turning, you finally give up. What do you do?
    """
    print '1. Stay in the room and find more clues'
    print '2. Attempt to use force to break the door'
    cluedoor = raw_input('Which Option? ')
    if cluedoor == "1":
        print "Staying in room"
    if cluedoor == "2":
        print "Attempting force"
if option == "2":
    print '1. Inspect the Rusted Cabinet'
    print '2. Go out in to the hallway'
    labhall = raw_input('Which Option? ')
    if labhall == "1":_
        print 'Going to rusted cabinet'
    if labhall == "2":_
        print 'Going to hallway'
```

Comment: I don't think a `break` statement is going to be valid under the `if` block. This will fix the `IndentationError` but will cause a: `SyntaxError: 'break' outside of loop`.

Comment: Maybe the portion of the code shown is inside of a loop. Besides the OP asked about the IndentationError, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statements are not going to be valid under the `if` block alone (unless the code you posted is also inside a [ `for` or `while` ] loop (which, in that case, you should post all of that code as well.). If you want the program to simply continue at any point, use `pass`.

---

What is it that you want to happen `if cluedoor == "1":` ?

> I wanted the cluedoor = 1 to lead to a different statement

Then you will write the statement under that conditional statement:

```py
if cluedoor == "1":
    print "a different statement"
```

Comment: This is not even an answer to the OP's question. Besides an `if` with only a `pass` would be pointless, you could simply delete both statements.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Do you really need to downvote my answer? That's not cool. The `break` statement, where it is in the example, will indeed cause in `IndentationError`. My answer provides constructive information.

Comment: the problem is that im trying to use two "if" statements at once that i want to lead to different things. I can't do anything because of the indents (and i dont fully understand how indents work). I wanted the cluedoor = 1 to lead to a different statement

Comment: But doesn't answer the OP's question, constructive information goes as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Constructive information sometimes *is* the answer. I don't think there was any reason to believe the code provided was already in a loop.

Comment: @user3882805 can you post more of the code? Is this inside a `for` loop or a `while` loop?